# Instead of getting a specific number of fetched pictures per page, I am getting a random number of items

Tags: javascript, fetch

```
function getResults(querySearch) {
  refs.list.innerHTML = '';
  if (querySearch.length > 0) {
    fetch(
      `https://pixabay.com/api/?image_type=photo&orientation=horizontal&q=${querySearch}&page=${api.pageNum}&per_page=12&key=${api.key}`,
    )
      .then(data => {
        return data.json();
      })
      .then(pic => {
        const info = pic.hits.map(item => template(item)).join('');
        refs.list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', info);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
  }
}
```

Instead of getting a specific number of fetched pictures per page, I am getting a random number of items. I don't why it's happening because the number of the items which should be fetched is hardcoded in url (12) . What is happening and what should I change?

Comment: It's possibly a concurrency issue, I would put the `innerHTML = ''` inside the `then` before your  `map`

Comment: Did you check what the API actually returns (in the network tab)?

Answer (score 2):

The API is working fine. I think the problem lies in your functions, e.g., template.

You need to be more specific about your issue and functions you use.

However this code is working for me:

```js
  fetch(
        `https://pixabay.com/api/?image_type=photo&orientation=horizontal&q=flower&page=2&per_page=12&key=api_key`
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((pics) => {
          pics.hits.forEach((pic) => {
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
            img.src = pic.largeImageURL;
            img.alt = pic.tags;
            img.width = 200;
            wrapper.append(img);
          });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: the template is fine:) i have figured a problem out with debounce.